# Laravel Job throwing Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, symfony-process

I have web application that runs a job to convert videos into HLS using the `aminyazdanpanah/php-ffmpeg-video-streaming` package. However, after about 2 minutes, the job fails and throws the error:

```
Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessTimedOutException: The process '/usr/bin/ffmpeg -y -i...'
exceeded the timeout of 300 seconds. in /var/www/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:1206
```

The Laravel job has it's time out set to 7200s.
My supervisor setup also specifies a timeout of 7200s:

```
[program:app_worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/artisan queue:work --tries=1 --timeout=7200 --memory=2000
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

I have also set my php `max_execution_time` to 7200s in the ini file.
In the job `handle()` function I also call `set_time_limit(7200);` to set the time limit.

I have restarted the queue worker and cleared my cache but that doesn't seem to solve the issue.

It seems Symfony just ignores the timeout specification from Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that it failed after about 2 minutes because in my `config/queue.php` file redis `retry_after` was set to 90.

```
 'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
            'after_commit' => false,
        ],
```

I increased that to 3600 so the job stopped failing after 2 minutes but kept failing after 300s.

I later traced down the timeout to be coming from `aminyazdanpanah/php-ffmpeg-video-streaming` `FFmpeg::create()`.
By default, the function sets a timeout of `300s`. So I had to pass a config to the function to increase the time out:

```
use Streaming\FFMpeg;

$ffmpeg =  FFMpeg::create([
            'timeout'          => 3600,
        ]);
```

And this solved the timeout issue.